# Git push not recognize newly created Gitlab project

Tags: git, ubuntu, gitlab

When creates new project in Gitlab, it provides with the following recommendations
for adding existing sources:

```
cd existing_folder
git init --initial-branch=main
git remote add origin git@gitlab.vbulash.site:neuroplatforms/neuro3.git
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push --set-upstream origin main
```

Unfortunately, last line produces the output:

```
vbulash@iMac-Valerij 21:13:43 ~/VSCode/neuro3 # git push --set-upstream origin main
git@gitlab.vbulash.site's password: 
fatal: 'neuroplatforms/neuro3.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

git user at gitlab server additionally belongs to sudoers.

What's wrong?

Comment: What's the exact URL of the web view for the new GitLab project? Does `git clone git@gitlab.vbulash.site:neuroplatforms/neuro3.git` work?

Comment: "git user at gitlab server additionally belongs to sudoers" ...why?

Comment: @amphetamachine sequence of commands is from new Gitlab project recommendations so all URLs are valid. git clone produces same error as git push, but repository completely empty

Comment: @JimRedmond error "fatal: 'neuroplatforms/neuro3.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository." appears before git become to sudoers. It's my attempt to fix this